# Using a variable to define a hashtable name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am reading a series of text files into hashtables so I can reference back to them in a script. The text files are well formatted to do so as name/value pairs.
The text file is formatted as:

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

where 'a, c, e, g' are the keys and 'b,d,f,h' are the values... except there are more than 1000 lines.

For example, I have successfully named an empty hashtable after a portion of my file name with:

```
$FileName = 'testName' #example

$hashName = new-variable -Name $FileName -Value @{}
```

Ref. Stack Overflow article [Calling/Setting a variable with a variable in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723845/calling-setting-a-variable-with-a-variable-in-the-name)

I now have an empty hashtable called testName. However, I cannot add to testName through the variable $hashName.

```
"$hashName".Add(1,2)
```

fails because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Add'.

```
$hashName.Add(1,2)
```

fails because [System.Management.Automation.PSVariable] does not contain a method named 'Add'. (makes sense)

Note that $testName.Add(1,2) works just fine, but in this does me no good, as I'd like to loop through several variables of $testName that I extract from the multiple files that I'd like to read.

Comment: `New-Variable` created the variable you asked for: `$testName.Add(1,2)`. What is the purpose of naming the variable dynamically? What are you trying to achieve that can't be achieved with just `$hashTable = @{}`?

Comment: If you want to create a hashtable per file, you could use a "master" hashtable to store all of those - e.g. ```$allHashes = @{}; foreach( $filename in $filenames ) { $fileHashtable = @{ ... }; $allHashes.Add($filename, $fileHashTable) }```. Then you can just access a "file hashtable" with ```$allHashes[$FileName]``` or iterate over the keys to process each "file hashtable".

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - You're right that `$hashTable = @{}` works equivalently well (and boasts brevity as well) to generate the empty hashtable. The failure is in _filling_ the hashtable thus generated. I should have been more explicit in my question.

Comment: Okay, so what _happens_ when you try to fill it? Does `$hashTable.Add('key', 'value')` or `$hashTable['key'] = 'value'` throw errors?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - As stated in the original question, $hashTable.Add('key','value') throws the error [System.Management.Automation.PSVariable] does not contain a method named 'Add'.

Comment: `$hashTable = @{}; $hashTable.Add('key', 'value')` throws that error?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - As you have it written there, the $hashTable.Add('key','value') populates a hashtable named $hashTable with a key-value pair, not populating a hashtable that has the name which is stored within the variable $hashTable. In my example, the hashtable I'd like to populate has the name 'testName'

Comment: So you want `(Get-Variable $FileName -ValueOnly).Add('key', 'value')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the *variable* you want to name based on file names - you'll want to use the file names as *entry keys* in the hashtable instead.

You can then *nest* other hashtables in the first one, one for each file for example:

```
# Create hashtable, assign to a variable named 'fileContents'
$fileContents = @{}

# Loop through all the text files with ForEach-Object
Get-ChildItem path\to\folder -File -Filter *.txt |ForEach-Object {
    # Now we can use the file name to create entries in the hashtable
    # Let's create a (nested) hashtable to contain the key-value pairs from the file
    $fileContents[$_.Name] = @{}

    Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName |ForEach-Object {
        # split line into key-value pair
        $key,$value = -split $_

        # populate nested hashtable
        $fileContents[$_.Name][$key] = $value
    }
}
```

`$fileContents` will now contain a hashtable where each entry has a file name as its key, and another hashtable containing the key-value pairs from the corresponding file as its value.

To access the contents of key `c` file named `data.txt` for example, you'd use the name and key as *indices*:

```
$fileName = 'data.txt'
$key = 'c'
$fileContents[$fileName][$key] # this will contain the string `d`, given your sample input
```

Comment: That isn't what I need. I need to be able to refer to a hashtable that has both the key and the value defined by the content of the file. As shown, this simply creates a hashtable of the file _name_ versus the content that I need to parse into its own hashtable. I think @mclayton has the solution brewing.

Comment: @ProgrammerByForce can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67575671/edit) to actually reflect what you're asking? What's the contents of the file?

Comment: @ProgrammerByForce Thanks, the sample data makes it more clear what you want to do, I've updated the answer

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen - Thank you- I believe I can make this work. I appreciate your help.